# Problem when minimizing user-defined function in Mathematica with Minimize[]

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to learn how to use the function `Minimize` in Mathematica.

I first defined the following function in Mathematica:

$$r(x,y,z,i)=\sqrt{(x-X_i)^2+(y-Y_i)^2+(z-Z_i)^2}$$

with the command

```
r[x_, y_, z_, i_] := Sqrt[(x-Subscript[X, i])^2 + (y-Subscript[Y, i])^2 + (z-Subscript[Z, i])^2]
```

Then I tried minimizing the following function over $x,y,z$:

$$ f(x,y,z)=(R_i-r(x,y,z,i))^2 $$

with the following command:

```
Minimize[(Subscript[R, i] - r[x, y, z, 1])^2, {x, y, z}]
```

The output I was expecting is a circle of points centered around $(X_i,Y_i,Z_i)$ and with radius $R_i$ (since at these points the function attains the value zero), or at least any point on that circle.

However, Mathematica outputs a very long and (for my knowledge level) cryptic solution. I can't think of any reasonable way to post the output here in a human-readable way, so perhaps it's easier if you try doing the commands in your Mathematica and see the output there (if someone thinks it's clearer, I can insert the whole output here, or perhaps a screenshot of it).

So my question is: am I doing something wrong, or is there a way to interpret this output in a meaningful way?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You need to have assumptions for your `X,Y,Z,R`

Comment: @Feyre, You mean like, assuming they're real/positive?

Comment: @Feyre: I guess $R_i$ needs to be positive, no?

Comment: Oh, yes. R has to be positive, the others merely real.

Comment: @Feyre: I tried simplifying the result with some assumptions but I get the same output. The command I tried was: 
`Simplify[Minimize[(Subscript[R, i]-r[x,y,z,1])^2,{x,y,z}],{Subscript[R, i]>0,Element[{x,y,z,Subscript[X, i],Subscript[Y, i],Subscript[Z, i]},Reals]}]`

Comment: I honestly also wouldn't be working with `Subscript`, it can mess things up too unless you're very careful.

Comment: @Feyre: I also thought that could be the problem, so I reformulated the Minimization call without any Subscripts. I still get the same cryptic output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. Your proposed solution is only valid if $R_i > 0$
2. The minimum is attained in every point on a sphere.  But `Minimize` returns only one point, not a set of points.  The documentation says,

   > Even if the same minimum is achieved at several points, only one is returned.

Simplify the result as `Simplify[..., Subscript[R, i] > 0]` and you get a clear minimum value: `0`.  The minimum point looks complicated, but it is valid: it is on the sphere.

If you only want the minimum value, use [`MinValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinValue.html).

To get a simpler minimum point, you could provide some constraints which restrict the solution to a single point, e.g.

```
result = 
  Minimize[{(Subscript[R, i] - r[x, y, z, 1])^2, 
    x == Subscript[X, 1] && y == Subscript[Y, 1]}, {x, y, z}];

Simplify[result, Subscript[R, i] > 0]
(* {0, {x -> Subscript[X, 1], y -> Subscript[Y, 1], 
  z -> -Subscript[R, i] + Subscript[Z, 1]}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I still fail to see how you can check if the minimum point is valid, perhaps you can elaborate a bit?